# Elasticsearch NEST MultiSearch ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When I try to use a very simple example of MultiSearch operator from NEST documentation:

```
var request = new MultiSearchRequest
            {
                Operations = new Dictionary<string, ISearchRequest>
                {
                    { "esproj", new SearchRequest 
                        { 
                            Query = new QueryContainer(new MatchAllQuery()) 
                        } 
                    },
                    { "people", new SearchRequest 
                        { 
                            Query = new QueryContainer(new MatchAllQuery()) 
                        } 
                    }
                }
            };

var result = _client.MultiSearch(request);
```

then I have the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2147467261
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>          in System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
>          in Nest.Resolvers.Converters.MultiSearchConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) w C:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\MultiSearchConverter.cs:row 101
>          in Nest.Resolvers.Converters.MultiSearchConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) w C:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\Resolvers\Converters\MultiSearchConverter.cs:row 78
>          in Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
>          in Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)

But only if I use Object Initializer Syntax - when I use Fluent Syntax:

```
var result2 = _client.MultiSearch(ms => ms
                .Search<MyClass>("esproj", s => s.MatchAll())
                .Search<MyClass>("people", s => s.MatchAll())
            );
```

everything is OK (I get results). Version of my Nest client is 1.4.2.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never tried the MultiSearchRequest approach.  I would stick with the fluent approach, that is going to be much more common and what is the way you'll find most people doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a bug.  Just opened https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/127 and will address this for the next release.